# Android Simple Mute Media Volume, but crashes button then app...?

Tags: android

I'm attempting to mute media volume, which seems to work but when button that controls mute on/off is pressed it crashes.

Here is my code:

```
SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
                boolean cmute = getPrefs.getBoolean("mute", false);

                if (cmute == false){
                    // mMediaPlayer.setVolume(0,0); <-- this causes crash of button/app, but works until then muting media volume =/                
                    Editor editor = getPrefs.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("mute", true);
                    editor.commit();
                    Editor editor2 = getPrefs.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("notice", true);
                    editor.commit();
                    SharedPreferences getPrefs2 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
                    View btn = findViewById(R.id.mute);
                    btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound);

                }
```

So, i need simple line i can have within the IF statement of this boolean that mutes media volume and does not crash button.

Many thanks.

Comment: what exception you got in the logcat when you clicked on button .

Comment: This takes two floating numbers.. So, try giving mMediaPlayer.setVolume(0.0f,0.0f)

Comment: Anil - no change, but thanks. BBdev - java.lang.NullPointerException at voice.recon$1.onClick

Comment: Are you sure that `mMediaPlayer` is not null?